# How do you append an element by an ID obtained with this.id to another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several pictures in the same class, and when the class is clicked I get the ID of the picture using this.id. I want to take that ID and use it to move the picture that has been clicked. I am trying to append it to the span with the ID "yours."

```js
$(".characters img").on("click",function(){
  console.log(this.id);
  $(this.id).prependTo("#yours");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "characters">
  <img src="assets/images/luke.jpg" id="luke">
  <img src="assets/images/rey.jpg" id="rey">
  <img src="assets/images/kylo.jpg" id="kylo">
  <img src="assets/images/snoke.jpg"id="snoke">
</div>

<div class = "text">
  <h1> Your Character </h1>
  <span id="yours"> </span>
  <h1>Enemies Available to Attack</h1>
  <span id="enemies"></span>
  <h1> Defender</h1>
  <span id="defender"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Instantiate a new jQuery object with the image (`this`), and not `this.id`:

Change:

```
$(this.id).prependTo("#yours");
```

To:

```
$(this).prependTo("#yours");
```

Answer (score -1):

While clicking on an `img`, target `#yours` element, empty it ( if desired ), then `clone` the clicked `img` and pass it to the `html` method since it accepts a jQuery object.

```
$(".characters img").on("click",function(){

   // Empty "yours" and add the cloned clicked image
   $("#yours").empty().html($(this).clone());

});
```

Comment: @downvoter i have revised my answer. If the reason was another, i'm eager to hear your opinion